# globalprotect option missing in network-manager VPN options

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openconnect

Ubuntu 19.04 has openconnect v8.02 which supports globalprotect.
I'm able to to connect to a corporate network from terminal using following command:

```
openconnect --protocol=gp <some address>
```

The issue is that it can not be defined in network settings (GUI) as the GP protocol is not available in VPN (only AnyConnect and Juniper options available under openconnect).
It is there on my personal manjaro computer.
Any idea how to add this option to Ubuntu ?

Ubuntu 19.04 with network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome packages installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GlobalProtect protocol option was merged into NetworkManager-openconnect on May 2nd, 2019.

Merged pull request is here:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/NetworkManager-openconnect/merge_requests/6

You can watch for this change to make its way into Ubuntu here:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openconnect

Here for Fedora:
https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/NetworkManager-openconnect/overview/